# Jest - How to write test expecting an imported component?

Tags: reactjs, tdd, enzyme, jestjs

Let's say I have a `componentA` that has imported components, `componentB` and `componentC`.

In `componentA`, I have a component method `someMethod` that based a props, it will output one of the imported component.

```
someMethod() {
    const { someProps } = this.props
    if (someProps === 'desktop') {
        return (
            <componentB
                href="www.google.com" 
            >
                {this.children}
            </componentB>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <componentC
                href="..." 
            >
                {this.children}
            </componentC>
        )
    }
}
```

How do I correctly write the test assertion for this?

This is what I have so far but it's not outputting correctly.

```
describe('someMethod', () => {
    it('should output componentB as component if device is "desktop"', () => {
        const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<ComponentA {...props} />)
        const correctOut = '<ComponentB href="www.google.com"">Blah Blah</ComponentB>'
        const output = wrapper.instance().someMethod()
        expect(output).toEqual(correctOut)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to render both of the components as shallow to get the same output. Equating a shallow component (correctOut) to a normally rendered component (output) will not be the same.

```
describe('someMethod', () => {
    it('should output componentB as component if device is "desktop"', () => {
        const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<ComponentA {...props} />)
        const correctOut = '<ComponentB href="www.google.com"">Blah Blah</ComponentB>'
        const output = shallow(wrapper.instance().someMethod())
        expect(output).toEqual(correctOut)
    })
})
```

Note: This would work only if `this.children` that you are rendering inside the component is equal to *Blah Blah*.